# WHERE aequivalent in R, multiplication conditional on another column of the same df

Tags: r, where-clause

i am trying to run a simple multiplication of a data.frame column with a scalar A respectively scalar B based on the value of third column (id) of the same data.frame. Somehow I have some (order,sort?) problem – so far the result is definitely wrong. Here are several tries:

```
mydf$result = subset(mydf,myid==123,multiplyme)*0.6 +
subset(mydf,myid==124,,multiplyme)*0.4
```

I also tried to use %in% syntax but was not successful either. I know I could MySQL for example and connect to R, but in this case I just want to use (basic) R or plyr at least here. Just for those of you who prefer code over my blabla, here´s how i´d do it in SQL:

```
SELECT
MIN(CASE WHEN myid=123 THEN multiplyme*0.6 END)
MIN(CASE WHEN myid=124 THEN multiplyme*0.4 END)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY result;
```

Thx for any help / R-code suggestions in advance!
Please note that I have more than 2 ids!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you only have 123 or 124 in `myid`:

```
mydf$result <- mydf$multiplyme * ifelse(mydf$myid==123,0.6,0.4)
```

If you have other variables in `myid` add an extra `ifelse` and a default case.

**EDIT:**

Since you have extra variables in `myid`, I'll state the expansion.

```
mydf$result <- mydf$multiplyme * ifelse(mydf$myid==123,0.6,ifelse(mydf$myid==124,0.4,0))
```

You can change the 0 at the end to a 1 if in the defualt case you want to keep the value of `multiplyme`. This can be extended into a chain of `ifelse` statements if you want to use a different multiple for many values.

However, as mbq comments below, you can use a `switch` statement if it begins to get unwieldy:

```
mydf$result <- mydf$multiplyme * sapply(mydf$myid,function(x) switch(as.character(x),"123"=0.6,"124"=0.4))
```

This would probably be slower though, as this will loop while `ifelse` is vectorised.

Comment: +1 for a nice solution; still for many myid levels `switch` will be more handy than a chain of `ifeslse` s.

Comment: Ou, I thought `switch` is vectorized... But than I have another idea -- a plain dictionary, like: `dict<-c("123"=0.6,"124"=0.4)` and then `mydf$multiplyme*dict[mydf$myid]`.

Comment: there are dictionaries in R :) ? i used them in python, but not in R. Did not think of that. Even though I had some more trouble and I just used SQL in the end, I accept this answer because it answers my question and I feel others (and me) can learn from it.

Answer (score 1):

The command should be:

```
subset(mydf,myid==123,multiplyme)
```

or

```
mydf$multiplyme[mydf$myid==123]
```

The equivalent SQL command is:

min(mydf$multiplyme[mydf$myid==123]*0.6)+min(mydf$multiplyme[mydf$myid==124]*0.4)

Comment: thx, Eduardo, edited my code. In the original code i used "==" just wrote it incorrect here. So unfortunately that was  not the problem here..

Comment: Your subset command is still incorrect. Take a look at ?subset.

Comment: thx for your patience, probably it´s just too hot inside this office and I should head to the Lake – i want to get this fixed first...

Answer (score 0):

If you really have two values of `myid` then `ifelse` is a simple solution:

```
> mydf<-data.frame(multiplyme=c(1,2,3,4),myid=c(123,124,124,123))
> with(mydf,multiplyme*ifelse(myid==123,0.6,0.4))
[1] 0.6 0.8 1.2 2.4
```

For a small number of possible values of `myid` you can use nested calls to `ifelse`. But `merge` provides a cleaner option if `myid` can take many possible values:

```
> multdf<-data.frame(myid=c(123,124),m=c(0.6,0.4))
> mydf<-merge(mydf,multdf)
> mydf
  myid multiplyme   m
1  123          1 0.6
2  123          4 0.6
3  124          2 0.4
4  124          3 0.4
> with(mydf,multiplyme*m)
[1] 0.6 2.4 0.8 1.2
```

Note that `merge` rearranges the rows, so you may want to have variables or row names to identify observations.

Comment: sorry for not stating: In fact I have more than 2 ids. Besides the merge suggestions helps, because my dataset has been generated by merge.